# Pass object of custom settings to nested classes

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, application-settings

In an MVVM application I have a Manager class that is responsible for grouping all the classes that my application needs and passing them in a single object to all the ViewModels.

This manager has a Menu class, a Customer class, and a settings class. In that settings class, I group all the settings that come from two sources:

- configuration of the App.Config file.
- configuration of environment variables from the computer.

The case is that if for example, inside my ViewModel I use a CustomClass1 and inside it a CustomClass2 and this class need a setting, I always have to pass a Settings object first to CustomClass1 and then to CustomClass2 with the settings already defined.

Is there any way to make this better?

Code example:

```cs
public class Settings {
    public string FROM_ENVIROMENT { get; }
    public string URL_OF_WEBSERVICE { get; }

    public Settings () {
        FROM_ENVIROMENT = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable ("ENV_1") ?? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable ("ENV_2") ?? "MY_DEFAULT_ENV";
        URL_OF_WEBSERVICE = Properties.Settings.Default.URL_OF_WEBSERVICE;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Manager
{    
    public Customer Customer { get; }
    public Settings Settings { get; set; }

    public Manager () {
        Customer = new Customer ();
        Settings = new Settings ();
    }
}
```

```cs
public class MainViewModel{
    public Manager Manager { get; set; }
    public CustomerViewModel CustomerVM { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel () {
        Manager = new Manager ();
        CustomerVM = new CustomerViewModel(Manager);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class CustomerViewModel{
    private Manager Manager { get; }
    
    public Customer Customer {
        get => Manager.Customer;
    }
    
    public Settings Settings {
        get => Manager.Settings;
    }

    public CustomerViewModel(Manager _manager) {
        Manager = _manager;

        CustomClass1 class1 = new CustomClass1(Settings);
    }
}

public class CustomClass1{
    public Settings Settings { get; }
    
    public CustomClass1(Settings _settings) {
        Settings = _settings;
    }

    public SomeTask(){
        CustomClass2 class2 = new CustomClass2(Settings);
    }
}

public class CustomClass2{
    public Settings Settings { get; }
    
    public CustomClass2(Settings _settings) {
        // Here, I need a Setting and the object pass from Manager, to MainViewModel, to CustomerViewModel, to CustomClass1 and finally to CustomClass2...
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems fine for me. If you want something smarter, have a look at dependency injection or IServiceProvider.

Comment: I´m a bit newbie, so I don´t see the benefict of using dependency injection here. At least in this case it´s the same send a type of object or an interface, I must instantiate the object before and pass across all the classes.. Can you give me any tip or suggest to do the things "smarter"?? Thanks for your comment!